# Is there an open source alternative to Dreamweaver's file manager?

Tags: open-source, dreamweaver

I always used to use Dreamweaver for web work, but now I work in Emacs, with Filezilla for non-text file uploads. What I miss from Dreamweaver is the easy synchronisation feature in its file manager. Is there any simple opensource software that would fill this gap for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer WinSCP as an FTP/SFTP/SCP client, and it's one of the few clients I've seen that supports synchonised browsing similar to Dreamweaver. SmartFTP is another one that does this, but it's not free.

See http://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_navigate#synchronize_browsing

Comment: +1, Very nice trick, I was unaware of such feature. =)

Answer (score 0):

[Aptana](http://www.aptana.com) does that and it's opensource; however, sftp support is not free. I would say it is the one of the better alternatives to webdesign. Give it a try, I've been hooked

Another plus feature is the integration of jquery, python, php, and svn. The pro version includes sftp support and cloud hosting, and i think it's around $100